# How to handle tab selection in Gtk# Notebook widget?

Tags: c#, events, mono, gtk, gtk#

I thought it will be easy, but...

```
// An empty Notebook defined in Stetic designer and created in generated code
Notebook tabs = this.TabsContainer;

tabs.SelectPage += (o, args) => {
    Application.Quit();
};

// Then I add some pages in code by calling tabs.AppendPage(...)
```

With this code, when I switch Notebook pages back and forth by clicking at tabs, event is obviously not handled. I tried also using other event (`FocusTab`), but handler is never called anyway. What have I missed?

Comment: I don't parse this sentence "BTW, in my application I really want to know only when a tab is shown at the very first time to user. "

Comment: @knocte Nevermind. It's not important. I may rewrite it, when I'll be in good mood again. English is not my native language. I'm sorry.

Comment: it is important, I have implemented some Gtk# code in the past with Notebooks and I have never needed to subscribe to that event, why do you need it?

Comment: @knocte In short, I need to subscribe to that event to know when user opens a tab, because I want to request some data from Internet only after that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I looked at the sources of gtk+ and it seems that the select-page signal is defined, but is never emitted (I will probably file a bug to mark it as deprecated).

I also noticed that the signal switch-page (which you should be able to subscribe via the event `SwitchPage`) is certainly emitted, so this should work (please report back if it doesn't and I'll take another look).

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it when at home.

Comment: You win. Yes, this works flawlessly. Now I just can't figure out why I missed it earlier...